# Is there a way to search for searchable text in <map...><area ... title="searchable text" /></map> and <img alt="searchable text" />?

Tags: html, browser, accessibility

Using <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> in most browsers will allow you to search for text, but only in only the text areas.  I would like to search for text in what should be accessible areas that are not necessarily text rendered areas such as `<map ...><area title="searchable text" /></map>` and `<img alt="searchable text" />`.  Is there a browser or addon that will do what I'm asking for?  This stuff is here for accessibility, but it doesn't seem to be really all that accessible (except by mouse hover, which again isn't all that accessible).

## NOTE

An answer that is required, *does not* use something that is decoupled from the view.  I.e. searching through the source code isn't an option as this is largely difficult to read (esp on complex pages) and doesn't show where the information is located on the rendered page.

Comment: If you hit inspect element, you can see the code where you can not only find but also can alter the text, elements , scripts etc

Comment: Yeah @TusharGupta, I had that idea, but it won't show on the view where the information is located, so that isn't very useful.

Comment: @Adrian did you ever find a suitable solution? I'm having the exact same problem. Thanks

Comment: @pgr, no, but I've written a bug up for this in either FF or Chrome.  I forget which.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a browser or addon that will do what I'm asking for?

Oh yes. Lynx browser does it.
But I guess it's not a solution ;-)

If your question is so, there is no way to override what CTRL+F is doing in your browser.

You can design a custom plugin inside your website, or an addon for your browser. This would be quite easy... but will require other shortcut.

If your main problem is to locate tags based on their `alt` or `title` attributes content, this is quite easy in javascript:

```
 var search='enter image';
 var nodes=document.querySelectorAll("[alt*='"+search+"'],[title*='"+search+"']");
```

You can then highlight the matching nodes using jquery or what you want.

```
for (i in nodes) {
   nodes[i].className+=' resultHighlighted';
}
```

and scroll to the first result:
    nodes[0].scrollIntoView();

If you intend to create a browser plugin, you can create your custom a bookmarklet or a custom plugin, and associate a shortcut to this bookmark (see https://github.com/iSunilSV/Chrome-Bookmark-Shortcut)

A simple bookmarklet to find the first match by title or alt attribute and scroll to it will be something like that:

```
javascript:text=prompt("search inside alt or title attribute");
document.querySelector("[alt*='"+text+"'],[title*='"+text+"']").scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: This is interesting, but unfortunately, not a complete solution.  Has promise though.

Comment: This problem is interesting but unfortunately a full solution will imply quite a lot of programming for handling everything like `aria-label`, `aria-labelledby`, `object` text replacement, `video` captions, and including normal text search which requires looping through every text node. I hope one day a future UAAG version will match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, use the "View Source" or "Source Code" function, and then within that window that pops up, use the Ctrl-F for Find.

You can also use the "Inspect Element" directly on an element to split the screen into two windows- one for code and one that's rendered.

For more information, here's a sample article for Chrome:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181951?hl=en

Comment: Although that will allow access to those attributes, it will also find stuff not associated with accessible attributes.  Also, it is decoupled from the view, so one cannot see the actual position of the rendered element in question. Because of these two reasons, this is not a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like the [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) browser plugin work? It's available for Chrome, FF and Opera. There are a few features that toggle the display of various attributes such as `title`, `alt` and even ARIA roles. This injects the attribute text inline with the element.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_area_title) of a html file using the `<map><area /></map>` tag.  Looking for venus should show it on the image as well as all the text areas.  Using Web Developer didn't do anything to make it visible.

Comment: @Adrian Your example is in an iframe, the extension can't access the content to scrape it for attributes. But after testing it on page with image maps, the attributes _are_ injected but not near the area of the image of which they'd belong. The injected attribute text can sometimes appear behind the image depending on styling.

Comment: Ok, so it is still not useful based on my criteria.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Idea 1

I assume you have Windows and Firefox installed

I have my Firefox installed with 2 add-ons.

1. Install a add-on called Tile Tabs, it make it possible for example left side is web view and the same page on right side with source code.
2. Install add-on called Web page to source code & viceversa that make it possible to toggle between view and source code by pressing on CTRL+SHIFT+S

Since what you required is not a default thing in all nowadays browses as far as I know.

Screen shot of the solution:

[image]

### Idea 2

Install FireBug, you can view/edit/debug source codes and view HTML live and what you highlight on the code will be also highlighted on the view.

Screen shot:
[image]

**Note:** Btw idea 1 is not only good for view / source code but it is also good to compare two views or read article to the right and answer question to the left.

Comment: A quote that I stated in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32255084/1366368) answer: `Although that will allow access to those attributes, it will also find stuff not associated with accessible attributes. Also, it is decoupled from the view, so one cannot see the actual position of the rendered element in question. Because of these two reasons, this is not a suitable solution.`

Comment: Although these add ons are interesting, they do not unfortunately keep the information coupled such that I can easily see on the view port where the related viewable object is located.  This isn't too bad on a small web page, but can become very tedious to find on a large one.  Thanks for the try though.

Comment: I agree with you but sadly so far I have not seen a solution yet, maybe it is some where out there but who knows. ;) Btw vote-up for the question. The only relation to both views are a tiny function that makes both views scroll synced.

Comment: @Adrian btw have you tried FireBug you can search in html code and it will highlight the view of what you search, let me know

Comment: Sadly, same issue.  Needs to couple not decouple the actual text found to where the rendered content appears.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's not a bug; they were just not designed for this use.

As I'm sure you are aware, the `alt` attribute replaces the image when it's not available. So how could you scroll to something that is not always displayed? Whereas you seem to be after a permanent description; a `figcaption` would be more appropriate for this.

As for the `title` attribute, it was [intended](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html) to merely clarify the purpose of a link. There should not be any new information to the user in the `title`; therefore I think it would be redundant to have two lots of the same information highlighted in one place.

The purpose of searching is to find text on screen, seeing as neither `title` or `alt` are *always* displayed I think the user would be more confused by the fact that nothing is highlighted, and that they are just taken to an image or random link/`area`. If the image has a `figcaption` that becomes highlighted, then it would make sense to them. Besides, how are they going to search for the title if they don't know what to search for? `Title` and `alt` do not come up in text displayed by search engines; the user will never know about it unless they've been to your site before, in which case they'll know where to look.

---

Also you state the following:

> This stuff is here for accessibility, but it doesn't seem to be really all that accessible

Which, understandably, seems true to you as you probably do not need it. However `alt` and `title` are read out to those who use screen readers so isn't entirely useless.

Comment: I actually didn't say that it was necessarily a bug.  In my view, it is a deficiency.  Accessibility isn't just reading out a page to the visually impaired, it should also allow for the visually impaired to be able to find stuff (e.g. images, links on a image map, etc).  You can scroll to where the rendered item was found. A figcaption is interesting, but it still doesn't address the problem stated. To eliminate confusion, a balloon could point at the location with a title indicating why it is being pointed at, a highlighted border would show the extents, and if selectable, it could select it.

Comment: Note, that this would also be good for all people, not just the handicapped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search funktion in Chrome's developer tools "Elements" Tab (Press F12 -> Tab "Elements" -> Press CTRL + F) and use XPath on your searches. Example:

```
//*[@title="Google"]
```

Matches will be shown with a yellow background in the code and when you hover it, its position will be hightlited in the view.

[Dev Tools "Element" Search with XPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeNwR.png)

It is coupled with the view, allows you to see the element's position and it's also an out-of-the-box solution in Chrome (tested in Chromium 45 for Ubuntu).

Hope it helps!

Regards

**EDIT**

Forgot - If you want to use wildcards on your searches, you can also do it like this:

```
//*[contains(@title, 'Google')]
```

**EDIT 2**

For the posterity! Further research shows that your goal might be possible to achieve using the Firefox-Addon Greasemonkey, which allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of JavaScript.

I performed several tests with this addon and could achieve a nice effect with simple images (display the ALT attribute as a DIV overlapping the image), but with area sections the thing gets a lot more complicated, as area regions can be squares, circles, and polygons with infinite coordinates plus retrieving the exact positioning of the area itself can be a bit tricky but maybe gives you or someone else a start point.

Based on the ALT Tooltips Script (http://greasemonkey-user-scripts.arantius.com/alt-tooltips-for-firefox), I created the following script and defined it in Greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Alt Tooltips 2
// @namespace   http://www.biterion.com
// @description Alt Tooltips 2
// @include     *
// @grant       all
// ==/UserScript==

function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}

function getAreaPosition(element) {
    var position = element.coords.split(',');
    xPosition = position[0];
    yPosition = position[1];

    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition}
}

var res = document.evaluate("//img",document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var i, el;
for (i=0; el=res.snapshotItem(i); i++) {

                if(el.alt) {

                    alternate = el.alt

                } else {
                    alternate = "No alt text";
                }

                position = getPosition(el);

                var newDIV = document.createElement ('div');

                newDIV.innerHTML = "<div style='position:absolute;background:yellow;color:black;top:" + position["y"] + ";left:" + position["x"] + "' id=" + i + ">" + alternate + "</div>";
                document.body.appendChild(newDIV);
}

var res2 = document.evaluate("//area",document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var i2, el2;
for (i2=0; el2=res2.snapshotItem(i2); i2++) {

                if(el2.alt) {

                    alternate2 = el2.alt

                } else {
                    alternate2 = "No alt text";
                }

                position2 = getAreaPosition(el2);

                var newDIV2 = document.createElement('div');

                newDIV2.innerHTML = "<div style='position:absolute;background:yellow;color:black;top:" + position2["y"] + ";left:" + position2["x"] + "' id=" + i2 + ">" + alternate2 + "</div>";
                document.body.appendChild(newDIV2);

}
```

As you can see, the script firstly detects all "img" and "area" elements, extracts its positioning and creates a new DIV element containing the "alt" attribute, which is then positioned on the upper left corner of the image.

As stated, the problem with areas is, that the positioning should be **relative** to the parent image and not absolute like in the script, plus the coordinates should be extracted accordingly to the type of area shape (currently only extracting the two first coordinates of each area, which will work for squares but will surely fail for other shapes).

Hope this will help someone :-D

Regards

Comment: That's cool, but doesn't work for maps.  It points at a place where the tag would show up if the map tag was visible, but not at the location where it is actually used in the image.  Good try though.

Comment: You are right and that makes me wonder if you'll find any other tool that provides the functionality you are looking for. Instead of that, why just don't use traditional image maps and use instead a nice CSS alternative (for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/oo297tuk/ )? It works like a charm with the proposed solution, by the way :-)

Comment: This question is not for any one particular site.  Perhaps this question should go to another site?

Comment: Huh? Im lost, which question do you mean? Mine in the last comment or your question in general?

Comment: Sorry, my question. Your "alternative" isn't useful in the general case. This isn't for my Website, but for accessing *any* website. I was thinking that if the browsers don't support it natively, that a script (bookmarklet) or a third party add-on would be the way.

Comment: Hmm... That the proposed solution is not valid because because it wont work with image maps (pretty much an obsolete and not really used component nowadays as far as I can tell) could be discussed, but its anyway your call :-) IMHO the question is at home at SO since it has to do with code analysis.